# How to change date format in select query while retrieving data from database?

Tags: c#, sql

```
select [Start Date], 
       [Start Time], 
       [End Date], 
       [End Time], 
       [Agenda Description] as Content 
from event
```

.here i want to change date format to mm/dd/yy.

Comment: Are you using SQL server?

Comment: What is the datatype? What have you tried? What is your DBMS?

Comment: Use `String.Format("{0:mm/dd/yy}", datevalue)` or `datevalue.ToString("mm/dd/yy")`. Avoid using SQL for converting one date format to another, use front-end method (i.e. C# method) instead.

Comment: If you are retrieving dates you can either get them back from the database as strings, or get them back as dates. Which one is best depends upon what you want to do with them afterwards, and if you prefer working with SQL date functions or C# date functions.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific!

Answer (score 0):

USe This.

```
    select convert(varchar(10), cast(columnname as date),1) 
    from <your table>
```

For Your Table :

```
   select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[Start Date],1) ,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),[End Date],1) , 
   [End Time],
   [Agenda Description] as Content
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are use SQL Server 2012 or later then you can use `FORMAT` function

```
FORMAT ( value, format [, culture ] )
```

Eg)

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = GETDATE();  
SELECT FORMAT( @d, 'MM/dd/yy', 'en-US' ) AS 'DateTime Result'
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch the data from the database and convert it to string format like

`yourvariable.ToString("mm/DD/yyy");` for example,if you want to get the datetime for today in ur desired format

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("mm/DD/yyyy");
```

or you can modify your date format in sql query itself as below

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),columnname, 1)as **somename** from **tablename**
```

hope this helps,

cheers!